# How to use mongoose model schema with dynamic keys?

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

i'm using mongoose with nodejs, and i need to create a dynamic schema model,
this is my code:

```
schema.add({key : String});
```

key = "user_name", but in my db i found that the model take it as key

```
{ key : "Michele" } and not { user_name: "Michele"}
```

What can i do? thank you.

Comment: What about `schema.add({[key]: String});`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The same issue [`schema with variable key`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2010) is talked in mongoose,

> Nope not currently possible. Closest alternative is to use [`strict: false`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) or the `mixed` schema type.

**Update**

After Mongoose 5.1.0, we can use the terms ['map'](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps), maps are how you create a nested document with arbitrary keys

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  // `socialMediaHandles` is a map whose values are strings. A map's
  // keys are always strings. You specify the type of values using `of`.
  socialMediaHandles: {
    type: Map,
    of: String
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
// Map { 'github' => 'vkarpov15', 'twitter' => '@code_barbarian' }
console.log(new User({
  socialMediaHandles: {
    github: 'vkarpov15',
    twitter: '@code_barbarian'
  }
}).socialMediaHandles);
```

Comment: thank you but can i at least do this key : {type : schematype } passing another schema as a type?

Comment: @AhmedCommando, it seems another question here. However, you can try `var schematype='String';`, then use it in the schema `key : {type : schematype }`

Comment: This issue has been resolved inside the post above. Or you can check https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps

Answer (score 11):

If I understand correctly, you want to `add` a new column to your schema whose `key` is generated dynamically. E.g. maybe a collection of posts per user, where the heading of post is the key. If a user creates a new post, it gets added to his collection with the key as his post's heading.

When you originally did

```
let schema = new Schema({ id: String, ... , key: String })
```

mongoose took `key` literally, just like it took `id` literally.

The reason why you cannot add keys dynamically to the root of the schema is because then mongoose can't guarantee any structure. You might as well do `strict: false`, as others have suggested, to make the entire schema free-form.

However, if you don't want to make the entire schema free-form, but only a certain portion of it, you can also modify your schema to use [**mixed**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed)

```
let schema = new Schema({ id: String, ... , posts: Schema.Types.Mixed })
```

Now you can save all your dynamically generated keys under `posts` which is free-form.

You can also do above with [**map**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps):

```
let schema = new Schema({ id: String, ... , posts: {type: Map, of: String} })
```

This will allow you to create any key-value pair inside the `posts` structure.

Answer (score 2):

simply use this in mongoose schema,

`users: { type: Map, of: Object },`

this will allow you to insert data in below format, and you can put additional data against each user id.

```
.
.
"users": {
    "63149e352b575f267b80565d": {},
    "63149e352b575f267b80565e": {}
},
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
posts: { type: Object }
```

And inside posts key, you can implement any key-value pair you would like to

Comment: mongoose does not have a type Object

Comment: @AtinSingh Are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes. You can check it out here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#what-is-a-schematype

Comment: In the documentation doesn't exist the type Object and I don't know if is correct to use it or less.. but in real life is possible to use it.
Obviously, I speak a year after last comment, I don't know if a year ago there was or not.

Comment: I could not suggest without trying, so it worked at that time also

Answer (score 1):

```
const options = {};
options[key] = String;

schema.add(options);
```

Comment: this is really free-form dynamic add

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Krishan Pal's solution, it is now possible to mention the 'ref' property to indicate to which model/collection the added object id belongs to. This way, you can use 'populate()' attibute when querying to fetch the subdocuments using the id.

```
  statements: {
    type: Map,
    of: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Statement',
    required: false
  }
```