# How to create or update within object of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nested, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to access a database with the following difficult schema and want to update the `file_name` value if it exists, or create a new object with the `file_name` if it does not. As I have searched, the option `{ upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };` will update do the second bit, but the problem is how do you access the file_name key nested deep within.

```js
export type _ID = string;
export interface FileSchema {
    [_id: _ID]: {
        file_name: string;
        creation_date: Date;
        isPublished: boolean;
        content: string;
    };
}
export interface AccountSchema {
  ...
    files: FileSchema;
}
const accountSchema = new Schema<AccountSchema>({
  ...
    files: {
        type: Map,
        unique: true,
        of: {
            file_name: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 60,
                unique: true,
            },
            creation_date: {
                type: Date,
                required: true,
            },
            isPublished: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: true,
            },
            content: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched a bit, and have come up with the solution below, although not pretty due to multiple queries. For nested objects with a dynamic key, you must use codes like [`files.${file_id}.file_name`] (with ``) to access the object within.

1. [Reference 1](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps)
2. [Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228599/how-to-use-mongoose-model-schema-with-dynamic-keys/73670535#73670535)

```js
const accountSchema = new Schema<AccountSchema>({
... 
  files: {
      type: Schema.Types.Map,
      unique: true,
      of: Object,
  },
})
```

```js
// checks if file exists, if exist then update file_name
const files: FileSchema | null = await DB_ACCOUNT.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id,
        username,
        [`files.${file_id}`]: { $exists: true },
    },
    {
        $set: {
            [`files.${file_id}.file_name`]: file_name,
        },
    },
    { new: true, upsert: false, useFindAndModify: false }
);
const fn = genObjectId().toString();
// if file does not exist, then create a new file
const x = await DB_ACCOUNT.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id,
        username,
    },
    {
        $set: {
            [`files.${fn}`]: {
                file_name,
                creation_date: new Date(),
                isPublished: false,
                content: "",
            },
        },
    },
    { new: true, upsert: true }
)
console.log("X: ", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Mongoose but you may be missing dot notation to access nested fields, look at
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#specify-equality-match-on-a-nested-field

Comment: Hey dude, it seems it's related to that, although a bit more complex. I actually came up with a workaround solution. You can check it out below.